# Python TypeError: an integer is required weird

Tags: python, pickle, typeerror

```
wally=pickle.load(open("The Wall.txt","rb"))
usernamey=pickle.load(open("username1.txt","rb"))
wu=("\n", wally, "\n", usernamey, "\n")
apost=input("Enter your post below: \n")
pwickle=pickle.dump(wu, apost, open("The Wall.txt","wb"))
```

Don't know why this isn't working, comes up with error message:

```
pwickle=pickle.dump(wu, apost, open("The Wall.txt","wb"))

TypeError: an integer is required
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As unutbu pointed out, the third argument is the protocol.
You should group all the objects you want to pickle in a tuple like this:

```
pwickle=pickle.dump((wu, apost), open("The Wall.txt","wb"))
```

If you need to pickle a larger amount of data, you could use the `shelve` module that operates like a dictionary.

By the way, the files pickle creates are binary (or at least not human readable, depends on the protocol), so I wouldn't name them `.txt`. `.db`, `.pickle` or something like that would be better.

Answer (score 1):

The [third argument](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#data-stream-format) specifies the protocal, which should be an integer, 0, 1 or 2.